# Software to burn CDs and DVDs

Tags: software-recommendation, burning

I have been trying to use Brasero to copy CDs , but it asks for `toc2cue` and `cdrdao` installation, I tried K3b and it says K3b can not copy multi-tracks. Can anyone suggest a software which would not give me hard times (something like Nero but free). Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with installing additional packages. No way to get everything on a single installation CD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend sticking with Brasero. I presume you're trying to burn a non-standard disk image format and that's why Brasero is asking for `cue2toc` and `cdrdao`. You could just install those packages and be on your way:

```
sudo apt-get install cue2toc cdrdao
```

Although I admit that this is a paper cut in usability and you should report it as a bug here:

https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+filebug

Please explain *exactly* what you're trying to do, with what kind of files and what makes it different from burning normal iso files. Make it clear what you expect the computer to do (i.e. work without asking you to install extra things)

Comment: well , I had tried to install those two softwares but it gave me error saying that one of them could not be found ( I do not remember which one ) but surprisingly it worked this time with no problem. I googled this problem and it turns out that lots of other people had to download those two softwares and most of them had my problem : one of those two softwares could not be found ( I think it was cue2toc ) . anyway , it is working now , thanks

Comment: looks like it's spelled wrong in the warning for Bresaro, it asks for toc2cue, but the package is called cue2toc. A real issue and I noticed it when I was answering, but I assumed you had made the error and not Bresaro.